# Selected item in combo box to individual forms

Tags: vb.net

i want the selected item on combo box to open in individual forms.

i'm using this code in button but when i select a item two forms are opening

```
ComboBox.SelectedValue = "1"
Form4.Show()
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "2"
Form5.show()
```

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: that code wont actually compile, but it looks like it is working as expected

Comment: Hint: [Select ... Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim value As String = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
Select Case value
    Case "1"
        Form4.Show()
    Case "2"
        Form5.Show()
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Choose something...")
End Select
```